# Cumprod Plus added Number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
data = {'Change': [.9, .8, .96, 1.5],
        'Add': [0, 0, 660, 0],
        'Open_Value':[1000, 900, 720, 691.2],
        'Close_Value':[900, 720, 691.2, 1036.8]} 

   Change  Add  Open_Value  Close_Value
0    0.90    0      1000.0        900.0
1    0.80    0       900.0        720.0
2    0.96  660       720.0        691.2
3    1.50    0       691.2       1036.8
```

Currently, I'm using a combination of apply and cumprod of "Open_Value" * "Change" to get the "Open_Value" and "Close_Value" columns. However, I wanted to implement logic which will add the "Add" column to the current row's "Close Value" and the following row's Open_Value, but am having trouble figuring out how to do this while continuing to keep the cumprod working.

here is my desired df:

```
   Change  Add  Open_Value  Close_Value
0    0.90    0        1000          900
1    0.80    0         900          720
2    0.96  660         720         1080
3    1.50    0        1080         1620
```

Anybody having any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the code you’re currently using?

Comment: How does your desired df differ from your starting df?

Comment: The close value adds the value from the add column in the desired dataframe

Comment: @SiP my actual df has a few more columns, but is essentially the following and Open Flag = 1.              
            g = df.groupby(df['Open_Flag'].cumsum())



df['Open_Value'] = g.apply(lambda x: (x['Change'].cumprod() * 1000).shift().fillna(1000)).values
df['Close_Value'] = g.apply(lambda x: x['Change'].cumprod() * 1000).values

Comment: @ZacharyMarx add it to the question and not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use function `shift` to slide the `Add` column data up to the next row.

```py
df['Close_Value'] = df['Close_Value'] + df['Add']
df['Open_Value'] = df['Open_Value'] + df['Add'].shift()

print(df)
```

```
   Change  Add  Open_Value  Close_Value
0    0.90    0         NaN        900.0
1    0.80    0       900.0        720.0
2    0.96  660       720.0       1351.2
3    1.50    0      1351.2       1036.8
```

Once the calculation is done you could get rid of the `Add` column by using of the following instruction :

```py
df = df.drop(labels='Add', axis =1)
```

```
   Change  Open_Value  Close_Value
0    0.90         NaN        900.0
1    0.80       900.0        720.0
2    0.96       720.0       1351.2
3    1.50      1351.2       1036.8
```